# Is there a better way to work with Wildcards in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Consider the following java constructor header...

```
public FirstPair(Map<Enum, Set<Enum>> f, List<Set<Enum>> fr)
```

Now, I wanted to make this "future safe" by adding in some room for generics. For example what if I want to pass in a `Map<Enum, HashSet<Enum>>` for f.

... So, I changed the constructor to this...

```
public FirstPair(Map<? extends Enum, ? extends Set<? extends Enum>> f,
                         List<? extends Set<? extends Enum>> fr)
```

Does this look correct?
Is there an easier away to account for varying input types?
Or is this the best way?

**** SOME MORE DETAILS ****

Consider the following function.

```
static void foo(List<Set<Integer>> listOfSetsOfInts)
```

The following code will cause an error...

```
List<HashSet<Integer>> diffSetType = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();
foo(diffSetType);
```

The reason being that a List of HashSets does not conform to a List of Sets. I want to deal with this error through changing the function header, rather than leaving the burden on the function caller...

The only way I can think of resolving the error is to change the function header to this...

```
static void foo(List<? extends Set<Integer>> listOfSetsOfInts)
// of even more secure...
static void foo(List<? extends Set<? extends Integer>> listOfSetsOfInts)
```

My question is is my use java wildcards correct here? Am I overusing them? Is there a clear fix that I am missing?

Comment: Do you need to do anything?  Can you not code to the interface?

Comment: Well, this problem pops up all over my code. It mostly appears in static methods with input parameters.

Comment: *this problem pops up all over my code* - what problem?

Comment: Why not use `public FirstPair(Object f, Object fr)`? Do you perhaps want a clean "getter", something like `public List<Set<Enum>> getFr()`?

Comment: I added some more detail to the question if that helps. There is no clearcut problem, it is more of a style question.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: 11, also your answer below does not seem to work for me. I agree with all your reasoning. But something like a Set<Hashset<Enum>> will not automatically conform to Set<Set<Enum>>.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud handling everything as an `Object` works, but then again what's the point of that? You just move the problem elsewhere, you'd get lots of `ClassCastException` because you don't really know the types you're working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of the constructor, which (naturally) has its very specific type, which then isn't compatible with the type of the variable where you're trying to store it. To make this explanation dig a little deeper into the fun and excitement of Java type wildcards, I did a type parameter rather than your `Enum`. (All of this is using Java's `var`, to keep the code slightly cleaner. If you're using Java11, this code will compile fine, except for the type errors and other warnings that I discuss below. *Also, your original code has a problem with the Liskov Substitution Principle. I'll leave that alone for now and fix it below (4).*

```java
public interface Foo {
  class A { }
  class B extends A {}
  class C extends B {}

  class FooMap<T> {
    Map<? extends T, ? extends Set<? extends T>> f; // (1)
    List<? extends Set<? extends T>> fr;

    public FooMap(
        Map<? extends T, ? extends Set<? extends T>> f,
        List<? extends Set<? extends T>> fr) {
      this.f = f;
      this.fr = fr;
    }

    static void exercise1() {
      var hm = new HashMap<B, HashSet<B>>();
      var list = new ArrayList<HashSet<B>>(); // (2)
      var fm = new FooMap<A>(hm, list);
    }

    static void foo(
        List<? extends Set<? extends Integer>> listOfSetsOfInts) { }

    static void exercise2() {
      var diffSetType = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>(); // (3)
      foo(diffSetType);
    }
  }
}
```

Comments:

(1) It's also possible to get rid of these wildcards. Here's some alternative code that *will* compile, but you'll get warnings about unchecked typecasts. Assuming you're treating the map and list as read-only, then you could substitute the code below. *(Note: the Liskov Substitution Principle has things to say about this; see (4) below.)* Once you allow for mutation, then things get more complicated.

```java
    Map<T, Set<T>> f;
    List<Set<T>> fr;

    public FooMap(
        Map<? extends T, ? extends Set<? extends T>> f,
        List<? extends Set<? extends T>> fr) {
      this.f = (Map<T, Set<T>>) f;
      this.fr = (List<Set<T>>) fr;
    }
```

(2) The concrete type of `list` is `ArrayList<HashSet<B>>`, but we want to use it as if it's `List<Set<A>>`, which is allowed in the `FooMap` constructor's wildcards. Note that we're passing an explicit type parameter to the constructor to say that this is a `FooMap<A>`.

(3) The concrete type of `diffSetType` is `ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>`, which is compatible with the argument type of `foo()`.

(4) You need to think a little bit more carefully about the first type parameter of the `HashMap`, since we want to satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle, which means satisfying the "producer extends, consumer super" (PECS) rule. The first parameter of the `Map` is a "consumer" type, so we really should write the code like this:

```java
  class FooMap<T> {
    Map<T, Set<T>> f;
    List<Set<T>> fr;

    public FooMap(
        Map<? super T, ? extends Set<? extends T>> f,
        List<? extends Set<? extends T>> fr) {
      this.f = (Map<T, Set<T>>) f;
      this.fr = (List<Set<T>>) fr;
    }

    static void exercise1() {
      var hmA = new HashMap<A, HashSet<B>>();
      var hmB = new HashMap<B, HashSet<B>>();
      var hmC = new HashMap<C, HashSet<B>>();
      var list = new ArrayList<HashSet<B>>();
      var fm1 = new FooMap<A>(hmA, list); // okay
      var fm2 = new FooMap<B>(hmA, list); // okay
      var fm3 = new FooMap<C>(hmA, list); // type error (5)
      var fm4 = new FooMap<B>(hmB, list); // okay
      var fm5 = new FooMap<B>(hmC, list); // type error (6)
      var fm6 = new FooMap<C>(hmC, list); // type error (7)
    }
```

(5) `HashSet<B>` from `list` doesn't match `? extends Set<? extends C>`

(6) `HashMap<C, HashSet<B>>` from `hmC` doesn't match `Map<? super B, ? extends Set<? extends B>>` because `C` doesn't match `? super B`.

(7) `hmC` is `HashMap<C, HashSet<B>>`; `HashSet<B>` doesn't match `? extends Set<? extends C>`

Answer (score 0):

For your initial example, you don't need to go so far to support what you intend to support.

You have:

```java
public FirstPair(Map<Enum, Set<Enum>> f, List<Set<Enum>> fr)
```

But `Map` and `Set` are interfaces, so if you intend to use this with a `HashSet` or a `HashMap` for the matter, you can, because those are classes that implement the `Set` and `Map` interface, respectively, and consequently adhere and respect the signature you defined for your constructor.

If you think in terms of interfaces common to the entities you want to support, it should simplify your life, and the signature of the constructor and/or methods/functions you are defining. If you come to think of it, typically if you want to allow other types to be used interchangeably, it is because you can treat them in a similar way, for the context of the functionality you are making available, so the interfaces tend to resolve that easily for you right away, and if there is no such interface out of the box for what you want to do, create one for the purpose. It will likely be easier to document, read and maintain in the long run. I hope that helps.

Comment: will not work: `new FirstPair(new HashMap<Enum, HashSet<Enum>>(), new ArrayList<TreeSet<Enum>>())`;

Comment: @Lino: the answer's point is, don't do that. Program to interfaces, and life will be simpler. Using wildcards here is a lot of trouble for no benefit.